# Multiplicative Inverse all between 0 and 1

Tags: ordered-fields

Why do all "the" mutliplicative inverses in an ordered field stick in a bunch between 0 and 1?

It's given that $x>y>0 \Rightarrow 0<x^{-1}<y^{-1}$ and the 1 is its own inverse. So you get that the inverses of elements $e>1$ fall into $(0,1)$.

Why can't there be elements between 0 and 1 that are not "real inverse elements" (inverse elements of elements $e>1$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

$$e>1\Rightarrow e^{-1}e>e^{-1}\cdot 1\Rightarrow 1>e^{-1}.$$

Comment: I should have seen this myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because $0<x<1$ implies that $x=y^{-1}$ with $y:=x^{-1}$ (which is $>1$)

Answer (score 0):

The inverse relation is shaped like a hyperbole:
$$
yx=1;
$$
If you imagine the plot you understand why you can't obtain what you asked.

Moreover, I would like to demonstrate in this way what you said:

Let's take $x>1;\ x\in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. 
$$x=1+y,\ \mbox{for some}\ y\in \mathbb{R^+}$$
Now, if you have $x_1,x_2>1;\ x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}$ it holds:
$$x_1=1+y_1,\ \mbox{for some}\ y_1\in \mathbb{R^+}$$
$$x_2=1+y_2,\ \mbox{for some}\ y_2\in \mathbb{R^+}$$
Hence:
$$
x_1x_2=(1+y_1)(1+y_2)=1+y_1+y_2+y_1y_2,
$$
and, by definition:
$$
y_1+y_2+y_1y_2>0.
$$
Therefore:
$$
x_1x_2>1.
$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the point that you want to make here. I see the parallel to the hyperbola but what's the problem?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I'm sorry. The point is, that among real numbers (well, actually also among discrete numbers) every non-null number has an inverse. Thus, for every number x in ]0,1], it exists a number y such that xy=1, i.e. y is the inverse of x.

Comment: Okay, I didn't formulate the question really precise.